# How to tackle 'ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__122_0(Task<SqlDataReader> result)'

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

upfront: its clear to me that with this info I cannot get much help !?

> ERROR
>   Invalid column name 'StudentID'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__122_0(Task result)
>   (some more info below - can provide complete error report)

all is done in VS2019, (localdb)/mssqllocaldb, Core 2.1, using SSMS

> Invalid column name 'StudentID'.: I have a 'dbo.Student' table with a Key: ID int

No, I do not have a 'StudentID' explicitely defined anywhere!?

What I'm asking in fact: How can I get to the relevant/appropriate  info !?
e.g. : traces, logs, etc
I admit I'm stuck

> Error report:
>       SqlException: Invalid column name 'StudentID'.
>       Invalid column name 'StudentID'.
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__122_0(Task result)
>       Stack Query Cookies Headers 
>       SqlException: Invalid column name 'StudentID'. Invalid column name 'StudentID'.
>       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__122_0(Task result)
>       System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask.InnerInvoke()
>           continued
>       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery(QueryContext queryContext, Func> compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger logger, Type contextType)
>       ASC.Pages.Students.EditModel.OnGetAsync(Nullable id)

in Edit.cshtml.cs

```
    -
            {
                if (id == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                Student = await _context.Student    <---------------- Error on this statement
                    // .Include(i => i.OfficeAssignment) // eddie -
                    .Include(i => i.CourseAssignments).ThenInclude(i => i.Course)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

`if (Student == null)`

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert(object taskAsObject)
>       Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(object receiver, object[] arguments)
>           continued

Comment: In general, turn [EF Core Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) on and see which SQL command fails. Regarding the concrete issue, the name 'StudentID' is conventional for FK property/column to `Student`, so check out `CourseAssignments` entity mapping.

Comment: ok, will do my homework … additional hints are welcome

Comment: If you post the relevant entity classes and fluent configuration, we can tell what's the exact problem. Usually it's caused by improper relationship fluent configuration - EF assumes conventional name for FK property/column while the actual FK property/column is different (non default name). In this case the problem should be with some of the *many* table related to `Student`. If you can see the EF SQL log, you'll know exactly which one.

Comment: It seems you model `Student` and table `Student` are not sync. Share us your model defination and your current table.

Comment: Hi guys, appreciate your help. Being a 70+ hobby developer; all your hints shows me - I have to do some Homework in fields like C#, EF, Core, Razor, Sql .... In fact I'm taking the ContosoU ef-rp sample to just do this. I'm trying to implement a function to update the 'Enrollement' table (Student/Course relation) via a UI rather than doing it manually in the table.
Your answers/questions show me my deficits. I fear answering with wrong info would just waste YOUR time. Therefore, thanks for giving me some time doing the necessary familiarisation. Will come back when I know what to ask!

Comment: you all had a point which sent me into the right direction - doing my homework - in the areas: SQL, EF Core, Model definition. migrations.
Without going into the details - the main issue were FK mismatches.
This issue is probably not of big help to others - so, best to close!?